# Navigating deeply nested routes produces error - 'package:angular/core/scope.dart': Failed assertion... 'isAttached' is not true (angulardart 0.9.10)

Tags: navigation, dart, url-routing, angular-dart

When I navigate away from the deepest view into the next parent-view, I get the following error message: `'package:angular/core/scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 297 pos 12: 'isAttached' is not true.`

[Click here to view the implementation source code](https://gist.github.com/knshetty/10495102)

What does the above error mean? Are there any mistakes in my router definition? Could it be the placement of `<ng-view></ng-view>` in the deeply nested views?

How can one reproduced this error condition:

1. Navigate down to the deepest route i.e. all the way to one-of-the subview, as shown in the  screenshot-1 [https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=CCCEB2154F3BF15A&resid=CCCEB2154F3BF15A!869&authkey=AJQ-1hF_KUVNsYM]
2. Now, attempt to navigate into View2 (i.e. to the next parent-view), as shown in the screenshot-2 [https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=CCCEB2154F3BF15A&resid=CCCEB2154F3BF15A!868&authkey=AEZyo3s7A-el880].

The above two steps should produce the below error dump:

```
'package:angular/core/scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 297 pos 12: 'isAttached' is not true.

STACKTRACE:
#0      Scope.destroy (package:angular/core/scope.dart:297:12)
#1      NgViewDirective._cleanUp (package:angular/routing/ng_view.dart:132:19)
#2      NgViewDirective._show.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/routing/ng_view.dart:108:15)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:717)
#4      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#5      _onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:70:61)
#6      NgZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:54:16)
#7      _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:70:15)
#8      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#9      _CustomizedZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:654)
#10     _BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:569)
#11     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:333)
#12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263)
#13     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendData.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:345)
#14     _BroadcastStreamController._forEachListener (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:298)
#15     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendData (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:344)
#16     _BroadcastStreamController.add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:228)
#17     Router._leaveCurrentRouteHelper (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:630:48)
#18     Router._leaveCurrentRouteHelper (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:632:46)
#19     Router._leaveCurrentRoute (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:621:43)
#20     Router._leaveOldRoutes (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:504:30)
#21     Router._processNewRoute (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:484:27)
#22     Router._route.<anonymous closure> (package:route_hierarchical/client.dart:468:29)
#23     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:717)
#24     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#25     _onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:70:61)
#26     NgZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:54:16)
#27     _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:70:15)
#28     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#29     _CustomizedZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:654)
#30     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:439)
#31     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522)
#32     _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:303)
#33     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:354)
#34     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:706)
#35     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#36     _onScheduleMicrotask.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:74:39)
#37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:710)
#38     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#39     NgZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:94:23)
#40     NgZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:61:43)
#41     _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:70:15)
#42     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:449)
#43     _CustomizedZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:654)
#44     _BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:569)
#45     _BaseZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:595)
```

### Additional Information

Dart version:

```
Dart Editor version 1.2.0.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.2.0
```

Development Machine:

```
Manjaro Linux 0.8.9 64-bit
Linux kernel 3.10.36-1-MANJARO
(Note! Manjaro Linux is an Arch Linux based distro)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in the leave order:
https://github.com/angular/route.dart/pull/43

Waiting for confirmation.